# How to show number small custom icon like mail, iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a social networking app. I have a button and based on the click on the button I need to show a small icon on the top right corner of the button. it is a custom color and text. 
I know to show the default system number icon for like the one for unread mail you can get it from the shared application badge count. But I am trying to do something custom here.

I am thinking of building my own imageview (its background will be a custom png) and then within it a small text to show the number.

Anyone has experience with this and can recommend a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a imageView with badge image as the subvie of that button.

There is a lot of custom badge controls available.

Please check the following links.

1. [jobadgeview](http://www.smashingmykeyboard.com/2012/01/05/custom-ios-badges-with-jobadgeview/)
2. [CustomBadge](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge)
3. [Badge](http://www.spaulus.com/2011/04/custombadge-2-0-retina-ready-scalable-light-reflex/?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change anything on the home screen besides for the app icon, name, and badge value.  Do you mean on the home screen or on a tab bar?

**UPDATE**

If you mean a badge in the app, not on the homescreen, checkout @MidhunMP's answer to find links on how to do this.  I have used http://www.spaulus.com/2011/04/custombadge-2-0-retina-ready-scalable-light-reflex/?lang=en before successfully.

Comment: no I am not trying to change a badge on home screen, but recreate that behavior on a UIButton I have in my own app.